# Calling python script with subprocess.Popen and flushing the data

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

Ok so i've seen dozen of threads like that , but none of them gives a complete answer and everything i tried so far foes not work for me.

**1) Script that constantly outputs some data and flusheshs it:**

```
import time
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(5):
        print i,
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
```

**2) Script that calls first script with Popen and should be printing numbers one by one but for some reason does not, and prints them alltogether at once :**

```
import sys
import subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'flush.py'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE )
    for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):
        print line,
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

First thing i am a little bit confused is  in the **first** script is that if you remove the flush it returns output in one line alltogether O_O... I am pretty sure it is because of time.sleep but still kind of expected it return like a standart output constantly returning values 0,1,2,3,4  but not all together, ofcourse flush resolves it , but just strange, at least for me ...

**The main problem:** 
Is that second script does not return number one by one , but returns all in one output at once..... What i need is to see numbers popping one by one...

I read somewhere that it does not return EOF which Popen waits to close the pipe , thats why it runs like to the end .....

So what do i do or try next ?  *Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Probably because your subprocess is not printing a newline after each number.  `readline` reads until a newline (or end of file).  See if my answer here helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255802/having-difficulty-capturing-output-of-a-subprocess-that-does-in-place-status-upd/12256356#12256356

Comment: Well, basically i found solution to my question .  Here is the code that works although i don't really grasp the theory behind it [link](http://chase-seibert.github.com/blog/2012/11/16/python-subprocess-asynchronous-read-stdout.html).  Why do you have execute it in thread, somewhere i read not to block Main thread, but then again how it helps , if you still get the whole text together only in thread, that makes no sense to me , because i dont understand how it works i guess. Then the thing about setting file descriptor to non blocking that confuses me a lot too.

Comment: @Viktor: [the link that you provided](http://chase-seibert.github.com/blog/2012/11/16/python-subprocess-asynchronous-read-stdout.html) is unnecessary complicated. It works because it doesn't use `readline()` (that won't work for non-blocking pipes anyway) and therefore it doesn't wait for a newline that your child script never produces. Here's a [simpler solution that should be enough for line-oriented output in many cases](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279)

Answer (score 14):

As [@Warren Weckesser's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461843/calling-python-script-with-subprocess-popen-and-flushing-the-data#comment20145373_14461843) says, your problem is unrelated to [buffering issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20509641/4279).

`.readline()` in the parent process won't return until it reads a newline or reaches EOF. Your child process doesn't print *any* newlines at all so your parent process doesn't print *anything* until the child process ends.

The minimal fix is just to remove comma at the end of `print i,` in the child script.

This also works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen([sys.executable or 'python',
           '-u', # unbuffer stdout (or make it line-buffered on Python 3)
           '-c',
           """
import time

for i in range(5):
    print(i) # <-- no comma i.e., each number is on its own line
    time.sleep(1)
"""], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    print(int(line)**2)
```

Example:

```
 $ python parent.py
 0
 1
 4
 9
 16
```

The numbers are printed every seconds without waiting for the child process to end.

If you don't want to change the child script then you should use `readline()` that stops at whitespace instead of a newline character e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['python2', 'child.py'], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=0)
for token in generate_tokens(p.stdout):
    print(int(token))
```

where `generate_tokens()` yields whitespace-separated tokens:

```
def generate_tokens(pipe):
    buf = []
    while True:
        b = pipe.read(1) # read one byte
        if not b: # EOF
            pipe.close()
            if buf:
                yield b''.join(buf)
            return
        elif not b.isspace(): # grow token
            buf.append(b)
        elif buf: # full token read
            yield b''.join(buf)
            buf = []
```

It also prints integers as soon as they are printed by the child.